# QML List of Lists (2D data)

Tags: listview, qml, qtquick2

**Summary**: How can I nest one ListView inside another, feeding data from the outer model to an inner model inside the delegate?

### Data and Desire

I have an array of arrays of data in JS:

```js
[[ {t:0, label:"Big Bang"}, {t:5, label:"Earth Forms"} ],
 [ {t:0, label:"Alternate Bang"}, {t:3, label:"Cool Stuff"} ],
 [ {t:1, label:"Late Bang"}, {t:4, label:"Whee"}, {t:5, label:"More" } ]]
```

I want to display this as a horizontal-scrolling "timeline", where the top-level array represents rows of data and each sub-array represents items within that row, placed at various times.

[image: Excel-based mockup]

*Note that the timeline is only discrete at the millisecond level, with values out to the hour range. Unlike what this Excel-based mockup shows, a 2D grid of merged cells would be infeasible.*

### Code and Problem

I'm passing the array to a `ListView` via a custom `ListModel`:

```qml
Item {
    property var timeline: []
    onTimelineChanged: {
      rowData.clear();
      timeline.forEach(function(evts){
        rowData.append({ events:evts });
      });
    }
    ListView {
        id: rows
        model: ListModel { id:rowData }
        delegate: Item {
            Text { text: "Idx #"+index }
            ListView {
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: ListModel { id:events }
                delegate: …
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is populating the rows properly, but I cannot figure out how to pass the `events` data role from the outer `ListView` into the `events` model within each delegate.

Additionally, as I wrote this question up, I realized that each row may try to scroll horizontally independent of one another. I want them all to scroll as a group. This makes me wonder if nested `ListView` is the appropriate tool for this job, or if I should be using some other data-driven QML structure.

Comment: BTW, I know that I should create a real model for my data instead of passing through from JavaScript each time the data changes. I have my own (perhaps bone-headed) reasons for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign `events` to the inner `ListView.model`, for example:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: ListModel { id:rowData }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width; height: 50
        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent; orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            model: events
            delegate: Item {
                width: 80; height: 20
                Text { text: label }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When a JavaScript array is appended to a `ListModel` row, it will be automatically converted to a `ListModel` (however, Qt documentation says nothing about this). So when you access the role name `events` in the delegate in the outer `ListView`, what you get is something like this:

```
ListModel { //row 0
    id: events
    ListElement {t:0, label:"Big Bang"}
    ListElement {t:5, label:"Earth Forms"}
}
```

And I think it's fine to horizontally scroll all inner `ListView` at the same time by setting `contentX` or `positionViewAtIndex` to all inner `ListView`.

Comment: That array-to-model thing is both weird, and wonderful, and exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @mcchu It's not really automatically converted to a `ListModel`, it is usable as a model. `ListModel` is one of many model types usable by `ListView` and friends.